# How to display a contentItem based on another Items value in orchard

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I am trying to figure out a way to say have a checkbox in a page content type that would enable me to hide or show a projection of images based on that box being selected. What would be the best way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method you can use and I can go into more detail as you need.

1. Add a Boolean Field to content type and have it render as a check box
2. Use Placement.info to hide this Boolean Field from rendering (so it doesn't show anywhere)
3. Override the resulting Projection shape in order to inject logic into the view (I will assume you are overriding with a .cshtml file) which will access the value of the Boolean Field. This can then be used to decide whether or not the html should be output.

One word of warning with this method. Even for those times where you choose to not render the html, all the work of actually preparing the projection will have been done so you will take the same performance hit whether you show the results or not. The alternative to that would be to override the Orchard.Projections.Drivers.ProjectionPartDriver.cs (either in your theme or in another module) and decide whether to prepare the shape based on whether or not the Boolean Field is true or false.

Comment: how would i reference the Boolean field if its in another content/widget. still learning what's possible in orchard all the help you can give is appreciated.

Comment: Easiest is through the dynamic view model which is automatically available in views from shapes and contains a reference to the main contentitem being displayed: `((dynamic)Model).ContentItem.PartName.FieldName`. This will return an object of type `BooleanField` so you still need to call the `.Value` property. You can omit the implicit cast to `dynamic` if it's not needed, however I mentioned it for readability. Remember that the field is *always* contained in a part, if it's defined under the contentitem it is still in a part named `ContentPart`.